# Man hit by a vehicle, wakes up in hell but thinks he’s in heaven

Tags: story-identification

From what I remember, a man is hit by a vehicle and killed.  He wakes up in some sort of afterlife, which he perceives to be heaven.  He spends most of his time flying aimlessly in blue skies and slowly becomes incredibly bored, hungry, thirsty, etc.  I think the story closes with his talking to one of the residents who tells him it is actually hell he is in and has been all along.

NB: I *think* I may have read it in a short story compilation that also contained the story 'The Sound Machine' by Roald Dahl, but I'm not sure.

Comment: One of these, then? http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68377

Comment: That's what I'm looking through right now, but so far, to no avail :(

Comment: Reminiscent of the Twilight Zone episode [A Nice Place to Visit](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734544/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_35), but not the same.

Comment: One of these? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThisIsntHeaven

Comment: Reminds me of the "got milk" commercial where the guy winds up in "heaven" which has a ton of cookies. However, when he sees that all the milk cartons are empty, he realizes that he is actually in hell.

Answer (score 10):

The book is *[More Horowitz Horror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horowitz_Horror)* by [Anthony Horowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Horowitz), and the story is ["Howard's End"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1019846).

> A delinquent teenage boy is run over by a bus and finds himself in Heaven - or so he thinks. He becomes bored with the idyllic existence, and wants to move to Hell - but it is revealed he was there all along